# Couldn't match expected type `a` with actual type `Integer`

Tags: haskell, types

I have a `treeBuild` function does not get compiled, because the signature in the where clause:

```
unfold :: (a -> Maybe (a,b,a)) -> a -> BinaryTree b
unfold f x = case f x of Nothing -> Leaf
                         Just (s,t,u) -> Node (unfold f s) t (unfold f u)

treeBuild :: Integer -> BinaryTree Integer
treeBuild n = unfold f 0
    where f :: a -> Maybe (a,b,a)
          f x
              | x == n = Nothing
              | otherwise = Just (x+1, x, x+1)
```

and I've got following compiler error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Integer'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      f :: forall a b. a -> Maybe (a, b, a)
    at D:\haskell\chapter12\src\Small.hs:85:16
* In the second argument of `(==)', namely `n'
  In the expression: x == n
  In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 an equation for `f':
    x == n
* Relevant bindings include
    x :: a (bound at D:\haskell\chapter12\src\Small.hs:86:13)
    f :: a -> Maybe (a, b, a)
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter12\src\Small.hs:86:11)
```

What is wrong with signature of `f`?

Comment: How could you compare `x :: a` to `n  :: Integer` without `a` being `Integer` or at least having some known constraint?  Or instead of the rhetorical question: `==` is of type `a -> a -> Bool` so if one of them is an integer then both of them should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The error

In your program you write:

```
treeBuild :: Integer -> BinaryTree Integer
treeBuild n = unfold f 0
    where f :: a -> Maybe (a,b,a)
          f x
              | x == n = Nothing
              | otherwise = Just (x+1, x, x+1)
```

So that means that you want to check the equality between an `Integer` and an `a`. But `(==)` has type signature: [`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-). So that means in Haskell the two **operands should have the same type**.

You thus have two options: (1) you specify the `f` function, or (2) you generalize the `treeBuild` function.

## Specialize the `f` function

```
treeBuild :: Integer -> BinaryTree Integer
treeBuild n = unfold f 0
    where f :: Integer -> Maybe (Integer,Integer,Integer)
          f x
              | x == n = Nothing
              | otherwise = Just (x+1, x, x+1)
```

Here we simply make `f` a function `f :: Integer -> Maybe (Integer,Integer,Integer)`.

## Generalize the `treeBuild` function

We can - and this is more recommended - generalize the `treeBuild` function (and slightly specialize the `f` function):

```
treeBuild :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> BinaryTree a
treeBuild n = unfold f 0
    where f x
              | x == n = Nothing
              | otherwise = Just (x+1, x, x+1)
```

Then `f` will have the type `f :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> Maybe (a,a,a)`.

Since now we can build trees for any type that is a numerical type and supports equality.

Comment: In my example, the variable `a` has no type, that because it does not work right? I did not clarify the type of  `a`.

Comment: `a` is not a variable, it is a type variable. You do not have to clarify the type of `a` in order to define a function. Haskell can derive the concrete types when you call a function itself.

Comment: OK yes, sorry. So the type variable `a` has not assigned to a type yet, that because it does not work right?

Comment: @zero_coding: well you specify an `f`, but in the *scope* of `treeBuild`. So that means that you specify a "free a" so to speak, and that conflicts with the `unfold` call.

Comment: Could you please show me another example of "free a"? Or what do you mean with "free a"?

Comment: @zero_coding: I think you should read about [Scoped Type Variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables).